# C - Looping/Navigating using goto

Tags: c

I am attempting to use the goto and labels to navigate through this program, however when I do navigate through the program the results aren't as expected.

When you load the program, it should ask you to input the amount of students in the class. When you input a non-numeric value it should send you back to re-enter the value. However it seems to keep progressing through the program. When you enter a numeric value, it should progress through the rest of the program as normal. However it seems to continue to loop as well. Lastly, here are no errors/warning provided by my compiler.

Question(s): Is there a fault I am missing in my code? Is there a better method to accomplish what I am attempting to do? Would it be better/smarter to just re-write the program using functions and while loops, instead of attempting to use a procedural/simplistic approach?

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int areStudents;

struct Student
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char address[50];
    char phone[20];
};

int main() 
{
    char userInput1, userInput2, currentName[50], currentAddress[50], currentPhone[20];
    begining:
    printf("\nEnter the number of students in the class: ");
    scanf("%c", &userInput1);
    if(!isdigit(userInput1))
    {
        printf("\nThe input you selected was not valid. Please enter another option\n");
        //userInput1 = '0';
        goto begining;
    } else if(isdigit(userInput1)){
        // asks users to input P, E, H
        struct Student student[userInput1];
        label1:
        printf("=>Press P to print the list\n\n=>Press E to enter the student data\n\n=>Press H For help\nPlease enter your selection: ");
        scanf("%c", &userInput2);

        switch(userInput2) // switch for choices P, E, and H
        {
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
            if(areStudents != 1)
            {
                printf("\n**You have not set any student variables. Please set them before using this option**\n\n");
                goto label1;
            } else {
                // print the list of student info
                for(int i=0; i>=userInput1; i++)
                {
                    student[i].id = i+1;
                    printf("\nStudent %d name is: %s", i+1, student[i].name);
                    printf("\nStudent %d address is: %s", i+1, student[i].address);
                    printf("\nStudent %d phone number is: %s", i+1, student[i].phone);
                }
                break;
            }

            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            for(int j=0; j>=userInput1; j++)
            {
                student[j].id = j+1;
                printf("\nStudent %d name is: ", j+1);
                scanf("%s", currentName);
                strcpy(student[j].name, currentName);

                printf("\nStudent %d address is: ", j+1);
                scanf ("%s", currentAddress);
                strcpy(student[j].address, currentAddress);

                printf("\nStudent %d phone number is: ", j+1);
                scanf("%s", currentPhone);
                strcpy(student[j].phone, currentPhone);
            }
            areStudents = 1;
            goto label1;

            case 'h':
            case 'H':
            printf("Select E or e to enter the data entry mode.\n\nAfter you have entered all your data, you can print the data by entering p or P.\n\nYou can only print after entering your data... otherwise, you will see some garbage values.");

            default:
            goto label1;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Result (non numerical):

```
Enter the number of students in the class: d

The input you selected was not valid. Please enter another option

Enter the number of students in the class: 
The input you selected was not valid. Please enter another option

Enter the number of students in the class:
```

Result (numerical):

```
Enter the number of students in the class: 3
=>Press P to print the list

=>Press E to enter the student data

=>Press H For help
Please enter your selection: =>Press P to print the list

=>Press E to enter the student data

=>Press H For help
Please enter your selection:
```

Comment: *Would it be better/smarter to just re-write the program using functions and while loops, instead of attempting to use a procedural/simplistic approach?* **Yes**

Answer (score 0):

First of, it seems like the program skips the scanf line itself.
Try this, provide a space before %c, for every scanf there is in the program. Eg:
`scanf(" %c",&userInput1);`

Also, initialize the areStudents variable to 0 and in the for loop with j,the code is
`for(j=0;j>=userInput1;j++)`
If you have noticed, the the 2nd condition must be "j<=userInput1".